# What is the best SessionRepository implementation for local developments/tests when using Spring Session?

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-session

I am in reference to the new **Spring Session library:** [see **Spring Session**](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session).

Spring Session allows one to use Redis (amongst others) in order to store Http session data  thereby being compatible with Heroku/Cloudfoundry when they recycle the dynos/instances.

I want to use Spring profiles in order to have two different environments:

- A ***cloud*** environment (based for instance on a `RedisOperationsSessionRepository`)
- A ***dev*** environment (based on ????)

Is `MapSessionRepository` the most appropriate implementation for my ***dev*** environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is really best practice to use the same setup as you will use in production. This ensures that you are able to find bugs faster. Redis is really quite easy to setup. In fact, if you look at a lot of the [samples](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/tree/b3130edd98537d866b7095ecd06b0cffc250c284/samples), they start an embedded Redis instance (you could do this for dev).

Comment: I tried to configure an embedded Redis instance and it attempted to connect to the real server resulting in an exception. Does anyone know why that is? I opened a separate thread here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29059794/