# Embedded Redis tries to connect to real Redis server, resulting in an exception

Tags: spring, redis, spring-session

I am trying to use embedded redis for my `dev` spring profile (I also have a `cloud` profile that connects to a real redis).

However, it seems that my embedded redis configuration tries to connect to the real redis.

Here is the error I get when I run the `dev` profile:

```
Caused by: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisDataException: NOAUTH Authentication required.
    at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.processError(Protocol.java:113)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.process(Protocol.java:131)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.read(Protocol.java:200)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.readProtocolWithCheckingBroken(Connection.java:285)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.getBinaryMultiBulkReply(Connection.java:221)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.getMultiBulkReply(Connection.java:214)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Jedis.configGet(Jedis.java:2758)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnection.getConfig(JedisConnection.java:554)
    ... 19 more
```

The `JedisDataException NOAUTH` is because I have activated authentication on the real Redis server and it tries to connect to the real server...

Here is my Spring configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class RedisConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory;

    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<String, String> redisTemplate() {
        RedisTemplate<String, String> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<String, String>();
        redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(redisConnectionFactory);
        return redisTemplate;
    }
}
```

"dev" and "test" configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableRedisHttpSession
@Profile({ Profiles.DEV, Profiles.TEST })
public class RedisDevTestSessionConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory() {
        return new JedisConnectionFactory();
    }

    @Bean
    public RedisServerBean redisServer() {
        return new RedisServerBean();
    }

    class RedisServerBean implements InitializingBean, DisposableBean {
        private RedisServer redisServer;

        public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
            redisServer = new RedisServer(Protocol.DEFAULT_PORT);
            redisServer.start();
        }

        public void destroy() throws Exception {
            if (redisServer != null) {
                redisServer.stop();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Cloud configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableRedisHttpSession
@Profile(Profiles.CLOUD)
public class RedisCloudSessionConfiguration extends AbstractCloudConfig {

    @Bean
    public RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory() {
        PoolConfig poolConfig = new PoolConfig(10, 200);// TODO: configure!
        return connectionFactory().redisConnectionFactory("REDISCLOUD", new PooledServiceConnectorConfig(poolConfig));
    }
```

Here is my dependency:

```
compile("redis.embedded:embedded-redis:0.4")
```

Profiles:

```
public final class Profiles {

    public static final String CLOUD = "cloud";
    public static final String TEST = "test";
    public static final String DEV = "dev";
    public static final String CAPACITY_TEST = "capacity-test";
}
```

**edit**:

Here is what the exception I get and the corresponding configuration is given below:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'redisServer' defined in class path resource [com/bignibou/configuration/session/EmbeddedRedisConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't start redis server. Check logs for details.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:957)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:946)
    at com.bignibou.Application.main(Application.java:22)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't start redis server. Check logs for details.
    at redis.embedded.AbstractRedisInstance.awaitRedisServerReady(AbstractRedisInstance.java:66)
    at redis.embedded.AbstractRedisInstance.start(AbstractRedisInstance.java:37)
    at redis.embedded.RedisServer.start(RedisServer.java:11)
    at com.bignibou.configuration.session.EmbeddedRedisConfiguration$RedisServerBean.afterPropertiesSet(EmbeddedRedisConfiguration.java:26)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570)
    ... 15 more
```

Here is my edited redis configuration:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.DisposableBean;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;

import redis.clients.jedis.Protocol;
import redis.embedded.RedisServer;

@Configuration
@Profile({ "dev" })
public class EmbeddedRedisConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public RedisServerBean redisServer() {
        return new RedisServerBean();
    }

    class RedisServerBean implements InitializingBean, DisposableBean {
        private RedisServer redisServer;

        public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
            redisServer = new RedisServer(Protocol.DEFAULT_PORT);
            redisServer.start();
        }

        public void destroy() throws Exception {
            if (redisServer != null) {
                redisServer.stop();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your configuration for the cloud profile? Which profile do you have active and how are you activating it?

Comment: Hi Rob, The active profile for the embedded redis is the "dev" one. I am activating the "dev" profile with the "spring.profiles.active" env variable. The "cloud" configuration is given in **RedisCloudSessionConfiguration** above.

Comment: What does the cloud profile look like?

Comment: I have edited my post. Please let me know what other kind of information I can provide regarding the cloud profile.

Comment: What happens if you temporarily remove RedisCloudSessionConfiguration?

Comment: I have tried removing the *RedisCloudSessionConfiguration*: it just has the same behavior... Let me edit my post.

Comment: It sounds to me like the embedded redis is not being used, but instead an existing running instance of Redis that requires a password.

Comment: I have edited my post. The behavior is indeed different...

Comment: Perhaps another version of embedded redis is used causing the issue. Which one do you recommend using?

Comment: Spring Session uses com.github.kstyrc:embedded-redis:0.6 which is available in Maven Central.